# How do I estimate reasonable row limit on heroku DB?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, capacity-planning

I am trying to estimate what is a 'reasonable' number of rows the DB can handle for heroku Postgres plans:
[image]

Assumptions:

- 1 row: 100 bytes
- Reasonable indexes are created on different columns
- Most of the queries are done on a single table. So not many joins and
  at a given point only one table's data is in memory.

Here is a rough calculation:
    1GB Ram = 10M rows each of 100 Bytes.
    But what's the space required for

- Caching
- Indexes etc.

**So what is a usable 'rule of thumb' rows I can fit in 1GB RAM, 15GB RAM for simple query optimizations.**

It's fine to assume std Heroku architecture and any optimizations they provide.

Please share any experiments you have done or heuristics you have from your usage on this tier.

---

PS:

1] I understand that this is hard to predict accurately but I need some ballpark estimate to tell the client what plan we could use and what would be the cost.